Is there any top-similar command to monitor mysql processes?
I would like to know if exists any command to live monitor processes of a mysql server.
I currently use show processlist; but this is a mysql command (not a bash command) and it doesn't refresh automatically.
Is there any tool for this purpose?
I need it to check long queries and locks.

Maybe there exists some tool which polls the data from all sources mentioned in Accessing the Process List article and displays this data in some useful form.. but I doubt.

Try here - and links within for a few suggestions. Percona gets a few mentions with its PMM tool - not sure what it does exaclty, never used it! Signoz looks interesting - never tried it either. If you want recommedations (off-topic here), go to the softwarerecs site on this network.
